# Connecting to GeoServer REST module

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, curl, gsconfig

I'm a new starter on GeoServer.

I have a requirement where in I have to create a workspace, create a coverage store (GeoTIFF file) and publish it through APIs. I am using Python through the FastAPI framework.

I am running on port 8080.
I tried using geoserver.catalog library, requests library.
Both of the above methods, there was a problem where the connection was getting refused.

I then tried using curl commands to see if connection is getting established by simply running,

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XGET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers.json
```

This also returns a `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused` error.
I have made sure the username, password, url and port are all correct and the startup.bat file is up and running and I can access `localhost/8080/geoserver/web` as well.

This is my code,

```
geoserver_url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest"
username = "admin"
password = "geoserver"
workspace = "test1"
store = "geotiff_store"
layer = "test_layer"

geotiff_path = "image/vertical_resilience_index_30m_2000to2100_RCP4p5.tif"

def create_workspace(workspace_name):
    # Connect to the GeoServer Catalog
    cat = Catalog(geoserver_url, username=username, password=password)
    print("Connection success")

    try:
        print ("Workspace exist check")
        # Check if workspace already exists
        workspace_exists = any(workspace_name == ws.name for ws in cat.get_workspaces())
        if not workspace_exists:
            print ("Workspace with same name does not exist")

        cat.create_workspace(workspace_name)
        print ("Workspace created!")

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Could not create workspace!")

def create_coveragestore(geotiff_path, workspace_name, store):
    cat = Catalog(geoserver_url, username=username, password=password)
    workspace = cat.get_workspace(workspace_name)

    try:
        # Check if coverage store already exists
        store_exists = any(store == cs.name for cs in workspace.get_coveragestores())
        if not store_exists:
            cat.create_coveragestore(store, f"file:{geotiff_path}", workspace)
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Could not create coverage store!")


def publish_coverage(workspace_name, store, layer):
    cat = Catalog(geoserver_url, username=username, password=password)
    workspace = cat.get_workspace(workspace_name)
    coveragestore = workspace.get_coveragestore(store)
    try:
        # Check if coverage already exists
        coverage_exists = any(layer == cov.name for cov in coveragestore.list())
        if not coverage_exists:
            cat.publish_coverage(coveragestore, layer, store, native_crs="EPSG:4326")
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Could not publish store!")

@app.get("/publish-geotiff")
def publish_geotiff():
    try:
        create_workspace(workspace)
        create_coveragestore(geotiff_path, workspace, store)
        publish_coverage(workspace, store, layer)
        return {"message": "GeoTIFF published successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": f"Failed to publish GeoTIFF: {str(e)}"}
```

Comment: The command `curl -u admin:geoserver -XGET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers.json` works for me on Windows with the standard bin-zip installation. I can't say what blocks your connection.

Comment: Are you sure that your command window is on the same machine as GeoServer?

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the reply. I have figured out my issue. My geoserver was installed on my windows c drive and I was sending the request from my wsl ubuntu 22.04 system. When i replaced localhost with the ipv4 address, the connection was working fine!